# Show that number of elements in $(Z/nZ)^*$ is $\phi (n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that number of elements in $(Z/nZ)^*$ is $\phi (n)$. $(Z/nZ)^*$ is set having those classes whose inverse exists.

If we prove that $(Z/nZ)$ has elements whose inverse exists are those who are relatively prime to n. Then my question will be proved

So i write let $gcd(a,n)=1$

$1= as+nt$

$as=1mod(n)$

as ~ 1

so class of a . class of s = 1

i.e inverse of class of a exists

Kindly suggest is this correct or some alternative option

Thanks

Comment: $as \equiv 1 \bmod n$ means that $s \equiv a^{-1} \bmod n$ (i.e. $a$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^*$) that's all

Comment: so is my proof correct

Comment: You need also to say that, if $\operatorname{gcd}(a,n)\ne 1$, then the class $\overline a$ modulo $n$ is not invertible in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How to show in general that that class is not invertible

Comment: Well, if $\overline a\in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$, then there are $k,m$ such that $ka+mn=1$. But then, all common divisors of $a$ and $n$ divide $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Result:"An integer $k\in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ iff $gcd(n,k)=1$"

Now if $k $ is an integer satisfying $gcd(n,k)=1$ then $k\in (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$

Also as $k$ is a generator of  $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$$\Rightarrow$ $|k|=n$

Result:"If $l$ is a positive divisor of $n$, the number of elements of order $l$ in a cyclic group of order $n$ is $\phi(l)$ "

Here in our case $k$ is an element of order $n$. Here $n$ is a divisor of itself (i.e. it satiesfies the hypothesis of the above result) so the number of elements of order $n$ (Which are precisely all of our $k's$) is  $\phi(n)$

Thus $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$ has exactly  $\phi(n)$ elements.

The above results are pretty much standard and are taught in almost every basic course in group theory.